# how can to export Entity Relationship Diagram for postgresql of entire docker DB?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I have used Pgadmin to connect to Docker Postgresql DB, when trying to export the diagram it opens a local docker directory to which I do not have permissions, is there a way to download the ER diagram?

As a reference I have added a screenshot that shows the root where the generated ER Diagram will be saved, where is that root since the pg admin is a docker service from windows?
[screenshot of saving file ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2v1K.png)

Comment: Are you running pgadmin from a docker container as well? Please show us your setup configuration, e.g. in terms of a docker-compose file.

Comment: What exactly is "*a local docker directory*"? Why can't you gain permissions to that?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've edited the query to make it clearer

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes, I solved it by connecting Dbeaver from the host machine and exporting from there

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by connecting Dbeaver from the host machine and exporting from there!

```
DBeaver: use the IP of the database in docker 192.168.3.84 and the port asigned by docker 5456 for external use.
```